# Is there a way to import data from fidelity to google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the link: https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=TSLA

Is there a way to import data from the Compare section?

I found this formula to get the sector/industry: `=index(importxml("https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols="&A2&"","//div[@class='sub-heading']//span[@class='right']"),2)`

But I am not technically advanced :)

Also for this site:
https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/ownership.jhtml?stockspage=ownership&symbols=TSLA

Same thing, is there a way to import data?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=importxml("https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/fundamentals/ownership.jhtml?stockspage=ownership&symbols=TSLA","//h2/span[@id='lastPrice']")
```

what exactly do you need as information? To retrieve data from compare section, you need an id from fidelity, then activate special link mentionned in the form with all parameters.

Comment: How would I retrieve the information below the Compare section where it shows marketcap, total return, beta, etc?

Comment: After a long search, I did not find any possibility to simulate the query as the page was created. Since this section is built after the page has been completely loaded by javascript, GSheets will not be able to retrieve the data by itself.